# Install GAlib library on Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: c++, installation, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

I'm trying to install the MIT GAlib library found here:
http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/

In the process I have realized how little I understand about installing libraries.  So a link to a mac-centric guide explaining this would be very helpful.  What a make file is, why anything even has to be made? What folder I should store my c++ libraries in?... etc

Alternately a step-by-step guide for how to install GAlib would be greatly appreciated.  The instruction on the site are a little to vague for me: http://lancet.mit.edu/galib-2.4/Installation.html#mac

Thank you.

Comment: Try going through the unix install instructions. The page lists osx under the unix group on the main page and it separately lists macos afterwards. http://lancet.mit.edu/galib-2.4/Installation.html#unix

Comment: I go into the folder with terminal and type make: -bash: make: command not found.  Then I try 'make install' and get the same: -bash: make: command not found.

Comment: Then you will need to install make.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using brew:

```
#brew install galib
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# brew install homebrew/science/galib
```